# MySQL - multiple case when for varchars

Tags: mysql

I am trying to use CASE WHEN to count when specific text is withing the varchar column. I have been trying to crack it but I have an issue when second, third CASE WHEN is added.
The code I use and works is:

```
SELECT *,
    CASE 
    WHEN (Orders.Some_text LIKE "%test%" AND Orders.Some_text NOT LIKE "%found%") THEN 1

    ELSE 0 END AS Test
    FROM Orders;
```

Now I add the second CASE WHEN:

```
SELECT *,
    CASE 
    WHEN (Orders.Some_text LIKE "%test%" AND Orders.Some_text NOT LIKE "%found%") THEN 1
    WHEN (Orders.Some_text LIKE "%test%" AND Orders.Some_text NOT LIKE "%missing%") THEN 1
    ELSE 0 END AS Test
    FROM Orders;
```

And it produces errors in the Test column.

Results I want are just simple 1 when word test is found and it is without found, missing or/and during.

```
+------+--------------+------------+
| id   | Some_text          | Test |
+------+--------------+------------+
|    1 | test               |    1 |
|    2 | test found         |    0 |
|    3 | found test         |    0 |
|    4 | test missing       |    0 |
|    5 | missing test       |    0 |
|    6 | test during        |    0 |
|    7 | during test found  |    0 |
|    8 | abc                |    0 |
+------+--------------+------------+
```

The code to reproduce my dataset:

```
CREATE TABLE Orders
(

id INT,
Some_text char(255));




insert into Orders values (1,   "test");
insert into Orders values (2,   "test found");
insert into Orders values (3,   "found test");
insert into Orders values (4,   "test missing");
insert into Orders values (5,   "miss   ing test");
insert into Orders values (6,   "test during");
insert into Orders values (7,   "during test found");
insert into Orders values (8,   "abc");
```

Comment: shouldn't the second when be an else too?

Comment: [I can't reproduce your problem](https://rextester.com/RAMEH27060).

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need to check if both the words `found` and `missing` aren't there in the field, then set the value as 1.

Combine the statements like below and it should return expected output.

```
SELECT *,
CASE 
WHEN (Orders.Some_text LIKE "%test%" AND
      Orders.Some_text NOT LIKE "%found%" AND
      Orders.Some_text NOT LIKE "%missing%") THEN 1
ELSE 0 END AS Test
FROM Orders;
```

> Output

```
+------+--------------+------------+
| id   | Some_text          | Test |
+------+--------------+------------+
|    1 | test               |    1 |
|    2 | test found         |    0 |
|    3 | found test         |    0 |
|    4 | test missing       |    0 |
|    5 | missing test       |    0 |
|    6 | test during        |    1 |
|    7 | during test found  |    0 |
|    8 | abc                |    0 |
```